# Travel (living) cost in the US for two weeks (New York and Los Angeles)

Tags: usa, budget, planning, new-york-city, los-angeles

**PLEASE NOTE** that this question is more about finding out people's experience. I would appreciate it if someone shares his/her experience during US travel. I am open to anything.

I will be visiting US for about two weeks and living in NY (11 nights) and LA (2 nights). I have no idea roughly how much money in total I should be budgeting for. Please note that my hotels+flights are confirmed and pre-booked. My understanding and general knowledge about US tells me that:

- Travel costs around $100-200 (could be more if I use cab more frequently).
- Food costs around $200 (could be more if I eat in all good restaurants all the time).
- Tourist Attractions cost around $150 (could be more, depending on how much I am touring).

Because its US, I was trying to have the chance and visit Apple Store so seduce my temptations, but that might cost me another $700 depending on what I buy. Does anyone have any better suggestion or idea?

Comment: Are you not concerned with lodging costs?

Comment: Firstly, getting the site to budget for you is now considered off-topic - it's just too complicated, too individual and too wide-ranging.  Some people would never consider using a cab, while you clearly would.  Tourist attractions - many are free, some cost lots, it totally depends on how many you do - and is practically impossible to know without knowing your tastes / interests.

Comment: @MarkMayo          I do agree, but I was more interested into people's experience, which I probably have not asked for very specifically. I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz       Already taken care of - Hotels + Flights prebooked....wasn't cheap at all, but booked :P

Comment: Remember it's a Q&A website, not a forum.  Just polling for people's experiences isn't really the SE way [help].  You're possibly better off hopping into the [chat] and asking there.